# Storing any number series data in a time-series database

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I would like to make use of time-series database InfluxDb to store data points indexed by another number instead of time which every data point is stored against. So I can take advantage all the features for a series of datapoints against this number..

For example I have a rocket doing multiple launches on which I have several sensors recording temperature, air pressure, fuel level &c. And I want to graph these datapoints against *elevation* not time..

I realise I could store elevation itself against time then from the time for say a temperature reading work out the elevation and project the results - but that working out would lose the performance characteristics of just querying the datapoints indexed by elevation. Also third party tools which use the time-series database won't be able to simply get these datapoints against elevation as opposed to time to graph them out, e.g. Grafana, without me putting something in-between to marry the data up..

One idea I had was to have a fake time where meters = seconds and store against this, then I would need make that a composite with something else to differentiate rocket launches, e.g. increment year by 1 starting at year 0.. So I don't see every launch starting at the same elevation and can separate the "number-series" from each other - I guess I would have that problem anyway and the proper way to that would be through tags..

Answer (score 3):

What makes you believe that this approach would be more efficient than storing the elevation jointly with your other sensor data? Fetching data is pretty cheap so the performance gain might be very light compared to the augmented complexity of your keys. Not to mention that you would still need to have the time make part of your elevation-timestamp, otherwise you will end up with duplicate pseudo timestamps and therefore incomplete data as most time series databases do not allow multiple values at the same timestamp for a given series.

I would encourage you to also have a look at other time series databases which include elevation as part of their standard data model. Check out Warp 10 for that matter (std disclaimer, I am the co-founder of SenX, maker of Warp 10).